# Is IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem supposed to work on ComboBox?

Tags: winui-3

Is there anything special to consider while setting this property ?

Just attempted to set but encountered the error :

[image]

[image]

Windows App SDK: 1.5.240205001

Comment: You could use `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem Property` on the ComboBox. Could you please provide a sample to help us reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, thank you for your comment. I added more details in question :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021206) and was thinking whether by setting this property could solve that problem or not. Do you believe that this property would influence the `SelectedItem` behavior as it was described in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021206)