# Why SelectedItem of ComboBox is 0 at first time while setting TwoWay binding onto source property?

Tags: winui-3

I wish to designate one item as selected from the `ItemSource` collection, so types are the same. The source property is set in VM's ctor and explicit property changed raised.

EDIT (according to StackOverflow guidelines):

UxSettingKeyValue's ctor:

```cs
SelectedItem = Setting.Available.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsChecked);

(Setting.Available is IEnumerable<SettingState>)
```

VM's ctor:

```cs
var setting = _provider.MakeByKey(ClimateCondition.Pm25.AsKey(), ClimateCondition.Pm25);
var caption = _languageService.GetResource(setting.Key);
    
Pm25 = new UxSettingKeyValue(caption, setting);
    
SelectedItem = Pm25.SelectedItem;
     
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem)); // It should not be neccessary since package <PropertyChanged.Fody 4.1.0> is installed.
```

VM's SelectedItem property :

```cs
internal SettingState SelectedItem
{
    get;set;
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.Setting.Available}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Caption"/>
```

Initially it looks like this :

[image]

Live Property Explorer:

[image]

The `ItemSource` seems to be properly initialized as the drop down values appear well;

[image]

(Currently all async operations rendered to synchronous for this debug purpose)

When I select an item on the combo box, the source property is set well, but initialy is 0 as you can see on Live Property Explorer.

EDIT as @Katana suggested to harness the `Loaded` event instead of ctor:

The call back is registered;

```xml
    <ContentDialog 
        x:Class="Weather.History.Mvvm.Views.SettingsDialog"
        xmlns:prismmvvm="using:Prism.Mvvm"
        xmlns:mycnv="using:Weather.History.Mvvm.ValueConverter"
        prismmvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myctr="using:Weather.History.UC"
        xmlns:myux="using:Weather.History.Mvvm.Model"
        xmlns:wctk="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
        Loaded="OnContentDialogLoaded"
        PrimaryButtonText="Close"
        PrimaryButtonClick="OnClose">
```

The event handler :

```cs
    private async void OnContentDialogLoaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            await ViewModel.LoadSettingsAsync();
    }
```

VM's LoadSettingsAsync method to initialize properties for the combo boxes :

```cs
    internal Task LoadSettingsAsync()
    {
        var dispatcher = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();

        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var setting = _provider.MakeByKey(ClimateCondition.AirPressure.AsKey(), ClimateCondition.AirPressure);
            var caption = _languageService.GetResource(setting.Key);


            setting = _provider.MakeByKey(ClimateCondition.Pm25.AsKey(), ClimateCondition.Pm25);
            caption = _languageService.GetResource(setting.Key);

            dispatcher.EnqueueAsync(() => Pm25 = new UxSettingKeyValue(caption, setting), DispatcherQueuePriority.Normal);

            setting = _provider.MakeByKey(ClimateCondition.Pm10.AsKey(), ClimateCondition.Pm10);
            caption = _languageService.GetResource(setting.Key);

            dispatcher.EnqueueAsync(() => Pm10 = new UxSettingKeyValue(caption, setting), DispatcherQueuePriority.Normal);

            // ... 

            await SeekMyHomeAsync(dispatcher);
        });
    }
```

Adjusted the source properties in XAML file :

```xml
                    <wctk:SettingsCard Description="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.Caption}"
                                       Header="PM 25"
                                       HeaderIcon="{winui3:FontIcon GlyphName=Accept}">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.Setting.Available, Mode=OneWay}"
                                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Caption"/>
                    </wctk:SettingsCard>
```

But still the `ItemSource` is initialized only. The `SelectedItem` is **0** until after I myself select one.

Comment: It's easier to help if you post code as text, not as images. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post,asking%20a%20question%3F).

Comment: Are you sure the `SelectedItem`'s binding is on `TwoWay` mode? In the image you posted, it's on `OneTime`, mode.

Comment: What type is the `Available` source collection? And what is `Pm25.SelectedItem`? Please edit your question to include all necessary details.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding @mm8 - Thanks, SO guidlines considered now! Yes, `TwoWay` mode was tried for size either but to no avail. I just have taken the wrong screenshot on the spur of the moment.

Comment: Check your `ViewModel.Pm25.SelectedItem` whether it contains valid data firstly. See [Selected item behavior change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/combo-box#selected-item-behavior-change).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT - Thanks for your comment. It is after OS 17763 but the selected one comes from the same enumerable as the `ItemsSource` had fed. `ViewModel.Pm25.SelectedItem` is set in a different thread and now I enforced an explicit property changed notification, right after;
`dispatcher.EnqueueAsync(() => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Pm25)), DispatcherQueuePriority.Normal);` and `"{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` but to no avail.

Comment: It seems that `SelectedItem` is not notifying its change to the UI. My first guess is that `RaisePropertyChanged` is not working as expected.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal sample? They work fine as @AndrewKeepCoding answered.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - Thank you. The method you suspect keep failing derived from `BindableBase` - [Prism.Mvvm](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs)

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT - Thank you for your comment. Yes, it works fine me too when I utilize the `SelectedIndex` property, I just wanted to know why `SelectedItem` isn't that case.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=OneTime}"
```

to

```
SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Sorry for the discrepancy, earlier attempted this binding mode either but failed to take the appropriate screenshot.

Comment: @Tommy try to set selecteditem in Loaded Event, if you are setting selectedItem in ctor, does not work. Add a Loaded event for your page and set item there

Comment: I just acted so but the `SelectedItem` is still 0 as long as I myself select one from the drop down.

Comment: Have you tried the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm from my answer?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding `Cannot apply [ObservableObject] to type Weather.History.Mvvm.ViewModels.SettingsDialogViewModel, as it already declares the INotifyPropertyChanged interface` this change would require me to alter other inheritance and a butterfly effect. On the other hand, Prim/Fody notification mechanism works well anywhere else.

Comment: @Katana when I initialize in the `Loaded` event handler, even the following property is missing too; ` <wctk:SettingsCard Description="{x:Bind ViewModel.Pm25.Caption}"`. When I initialize in ctor, this property is correctly set and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small block of sample code that:

- populates a `ComboBox` with enum values
- initializes the selected item

But, since I'm not familiar with **Fody**, I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package instead.

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace App1;

public enum SettingState
{
    State0,
    State1,
    State2,
}

// Make sure this class is "partial" for the "CommunitToolkit.Mvvm"'s source generators.
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // An INotifyPropertyChanged implemented "SettingState" property will be auto-generated for you.
    private SettingState _settingState = SettingState.State2;

    public SettingState[] SettingStates { get; } = Enum.GetValues<SettingState>();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SettingStates}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SettingState, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Comment: so far never was able to fix this, though detected 1 error in `LoadSettingAsync` as lambdas setting the properties not snatching the current values as they queued merely and obviously taking the last set values. Another lecture; WinUI3 not equals to WPF as for the prop changed handlers aren't marshaled back to the UI thread. After all, I utilized the `SelectedIndex` prop and retrieved the desired element again from the collection - a bit hack but `SelectedItem` never has init value for some reason.